# подключение библиотеки в CMake

Tags: cmake, library

Как подключить к проекту стороннюю библиотеку в CMake?
find_library, find_package не помогают...

есть папка в проекте
extlibs
в ней пути
bin/x64/lua53.dll
bin/x86/lua53.dll
headers/lua/*.h
libs-mingw/x64/liblua53.a
libs-mingw/x86/liblua53.a

код CMake

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE DEP_LIBS    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/libs*/*")
file(GLOB_RECURSE DEP_BINS    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/bin*/*")
file(GLOB_RECURSE DEP_HEADERS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/headers/*")

foreach(DEP_FILE ${DEP_LIBS} ${DEP_BINS} ${DEP_HEADERS})
    get_filename_component(DEP_DIR ${DEP_FILE} PATH)

    set(CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH ${CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH} ${DEP_DIR})

    get_filename_component(DEP_PARENT_DIR ${DEP_DIR} PATH)
    while(NOT DEP_PARENT_DIR STREQUAL "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs")
        set(CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH ${CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH} ${DEP_PARENT_DIR})

        get_filename_component(DEP_PARENT_DIR ${DEP_PARENT_DIR} PATH)
    endwhile()
endforeach()
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH)

if(ARCH_32BITS)
    install(DIRECTORY extlibs/bin/x86/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
    install(DIRECTORY extlibs/libs-mingw/x86/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
elseif(ARCH_64BITS)
    install(DIRECTORY extlibs/bin/x64/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
    install(DIRECTORY extlibs/libs-mingw/x64/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
endif()
```

```
find_path(LUA_INCLUDE_DIR_TEST NAMES lua/lua.h PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/headers/ NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

find_library(LUA_LIBRARY NAMES lua lua53)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(LUA DEFAULT_MSG LUA_LIBRARY LUA_INCLUDE_DIR)

mark_as_advanced(LUA_INCLUDE_DIR LUA_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

не вполне ясно в чем собственно проблема....
в документации Cmake:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html

Comment: это 3rd библиотека, мне ее нужно подключить к проекту.
она скомпилирована, пытался добавить через find_path/find_library пишет -NOTFOUND

Comment: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=CMake_Tutorial п.3.6 "Самое важное - подключение библиотек"

Comment: мне нужно без find_package это все дело подключить, дело в том что библиотека собрана вручную, find_package ее не видит.